# How to Externalize Query in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2-esb

I have created ESB proxy using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1

Currently DBLookup mediator contains following sql

```
<sql>select A, B, C from cis-dev.table1 where ... </sql>
```

Since, cis-dev schema is specific to the dev environment, I need to store this query outside the proxy in order to migrate proxy service to QA and PROD environments.

Is there a way to accomplish this in WSO2 ESB?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way store query outside and invoke it as per the environment. But you can parameterize the query and pass parameters with the request to alter values in the query . See the sample below

```
<dblookup>
   <connection>
       <pool>
           <driver>org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</driver>
           <url>jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/esbdb;user=esb;password=esb</url>
           <user>esb</user>
           <password>esb</password>
       </pool>
   </connection>
   <statement>
       <sql>select * from company where name =?</sql>
       <parameter expression="//m0:getQuote/m0:request/m0:symbol"
                  xmlns:m0="http://services.samples" type="VARCHAR"/>
       <result name="company_id" column="id"/>
       <result name="company_price_0" column="price" rowIndex="2"/>
       <result name="company_price_1" column="price" rowIndex="4"/>
   </statement>
</dblookup>
```

Comment: I am already using this approach for the sql parameters. However, I am trying to figure out how to externalize database schema e.g. cis-dev, cis-qa and cis-prod in our case. If I can't externalize it, the only option is to create separate car files for each environment. That is probably the least preferred approach as we are not migrating the same tested car file the next environment.